# Filter what gets plotted in MATLAB forloop

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a specific point in this code a little more elegant. I'm new to matlab and I'm not sure how to tackle this (See note right before plot in nested forloop).

Basically, I want to filter out all data where the initial conditions that do NOT start on the edges of the plot. (See attached picture). The way it is set up it graphs everything. I need to filter anything that doesn't start with its initial conditions on the edge of the plot.

```
%inital conditions
x10 = -0.1:0.02:0.1;
x20 = -0.1:0.02:0.1;


sig = -1;%needs to be negative for stable system
wd = 1;%needs to be non 0 for spiral (sign will give spiral direction)
t_vec = 0:0.1:10;

for i=1:length(x10)
    for j=1:length(x20)
        
        X0 = [x10(i);x20(j)];
        
        [t X1]=ode45(@(t,X) ODE_system(t,X,sig,wd),t_vec,X0);%solve ODEs
        [t X2]=ode45(@(t,X) ODE_system(t,X,sig,-wd),t_vec,X0);%flip direction of spiral
        
        figure(1)
        hold on
%***Add filter that filters out any initial conditions that aren't on the edges of the plot. 
       plot(X1(:,1),X1(:,2))
        plot(X2(:,1),X2(:,2))
        
    end
end

%define function to be used with ode45 solver
function Xdot = ODE_system(t,X,sig,wd)

Xdot = zeros(size(X));

Xdot(1) = sig*X(1)+wd*X(2);
Xdot(2) = -wd*X(1)+sig*X(2);
end
```

I know I could just add a lengthy "If condition" that is 40 arguments long (one for each of the arguments I want to have plotted). I am just trying to think of a fancier way to do this. I do see any relationship between the edge points that would allow me to reduce this "IF" condition to anything less than 40 unique arguments.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check whether `X0` contains either the first or last element of `x10`, or contains the first or last element of `x20`. And then put this check before simulating the ode, so you don't do any unnecessary calculations.

```
for i=1:length(x10)
    for j=1:length(x20)
        
        X0 = [x10(i);x20(j)];
        if any(X0(1) == x10([1,end])) ||  any(X0(2) == x20([1,end])) 
            [t X1]=ode45(@(t,X) ODE_system(t,X,sig,wd),t_vec,X0);%solve ODEs
            [t X2]=ode45(@(t,X) ODE_system(t,X,sig,-wd),t_vec,X0);%flip direction of spiral

            figure(1)
            hold on
            plot(X1(:,1),X1(:,2))
            plot(X2(:,1),X2(:,2))
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Arrh... so simple and obvious! Why didn't I see that!!! Thank you! Perfect!

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to `for i=2:length(x10)-1 for j=2:length(x20)-1`?

Comment: Maybe I messed it up... because I thought of that but when I tried it the end result wasn't what I expected. BUT I am new to matlab so its entirely possible that I screwed it up.